# Is it possible to get enum by string, when there is whitespace in that string?

Tags: java

I have a method that gets Enum by string value, but that method is case-sensitive and does not tolerate white spaces. How can I solve it?

```
enum MyEnum {
    ID("ID"), NEW_CODE("new code"), VALUES("values");
}

public static <T extends Enum<T>> T 
    getEnumFromString(Class<T> c, String string) {
    if (c != null && string != null) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(c, string);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            //If no enum value was not found
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why does `getEnumFromString` have to be so general? Any problem with implementing it in `MyEnum`?

Comment: There are multiple enums that i have to get by string.

Comment: Are you trying to do a loose compare against the enum name (e.g. `NEW_CODE`), or are you trying to do a normal compare against the string passed to the enum constructor (e.g. `"new code"`)?

Answer (score 4):

If you have arbitrary text to lookup by, then you can't rely on using `Enum.valueOf`. You need to expose the lookup text in the enum itself, then use that to resolve `"string"`.

The following makes the enum implement an interface, then uses the interface method to retrieve the "text":

```
interface ValueEnum {
    String getValue(); //pick a name that minimizes refactoring
}
enum MyEnum implements ValueEnum{
    ID("ID"), NEW_CODE("new code"), VALUES("values");
    private final String value;
    MyEnum(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

public static <T extends Enum<T> & ValueEnum> T 
    getEnumFromString(Class<T> c, String string) {

    for(T value : c.getEnumConstants()) {
        if(value.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(string.trim())) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By convention, enums should be uppercase and use underscores as delimitors(spaces are not even allowed), just as you did.

If you follow the conventions(what you do), you can use just convert `string` to uppercase and replace any spaces with underscores:

```
Enum.valueOf(c, string.toUpperCase().replace(' ','_');
```